Add extra runtime dependencies to Nix Home Manager package
In my Home Manager config, I have the following pkgs:
home.packages = with pkgs; [
    # Development
    emacs

    # Development - Emacs - Base
    ripgrep
    fd
    (nerdfonts.override { fonts = [ "NerdFontsSymbolsOnly" ]; })

    # Development - Emacs - Shell script linting
    shellcheck-minimal

    # Development - Emacs - Web
    html-tidy
    stylelint
    jsbeautifier

    ...

As you can see, all the other packages besides emacs are packages that my emacs config requires as "runtime dependencies".
I wanted to make things more clear and "scoped" by setting all these pkgs as the emacs pkg runtime dependencies.
I tried to do it with this:
    # Development
    (emacs.overrideAttrs (old: rec {
      buildInputs = old.buildInputs ++ [
        # Base
        ripgrep
        fd
        (nerdfonts.override { fonts = [ "NerdFontsSymbolsOnly" ]; })

        # Shell script linting
        shellcheck-minimal

        # Web
        html-tidy
        stylelint
        jsbeautifier
      ];
    }))

But this will actually just build emacs with these dependencies available only at build it, and then they will be "discarded" afterwards since (as far as I understand) the generated binary doesn't explicitly depends on these pkgs.
Is there some way for me to force home manager to see these pkgs as emacs runtime dependencies?

As you mentioned, buildInputs only provide the dependencies at build time. To ensure that dependencies are available at runtime, you should use propagatedBuildInputs.
Alternatively, you can create a wrapper for the program, such as Emacs, to explicitly set the runtime environment. Here’s an example of how to do that:
home.packages = with pkgs; [
  (symlinkJoin {
    name = "emacs";
    paths = [
      emacs
      
      # Dependencies
      ripgrep
      fd
      # ...
    ];
  })
]

